# Symfony2 - JMS Serializer - Exclude entity if getDeleted() is not null

Tags: json, symfony, serialization

I have nested OneToMany relationships. A form has question sections which have question groups that have questions which have possible answers.

What I need to achieve is, to ignore those sections or groups or questions or possible answers that are deleted (virtually using $deleted param)

Serializing without exclusion  or by just excluding property (with expression)  works fine.

But @JMS\Exclude(if="expression..") on class (not property) is ignored.

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="entity_question_section")
 * @JMS\Exclude(if="object.getDeleted() !== null")
 */
class QuestionSection
{
.......
}
```

The Exclude annotation is allowed to use on class "@Target({"PROPERTY", "CLASS", "METHOD", "ANNOTATION"})"  but it does not work.

Does not matter what kind of expression i use, it will exclude all fields inside QuestionSection entity and returns empty object for each QuestionSection.

How I serialize

```
$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
$serialized = $serializer->serialize($form, "json");
$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setContent($serialized);
```

If I will need to do it by doing nested loops to build json response it will be probably very bad solution.

I have googled few hours to get this done, i have also tried JLM\SerializerExpressionBundle\JLMSerializerExpressionBundle()  but it only supports to be defined on property and only exclude property.

I have also tried expression using service (if="service('general').isDeleted(object)")

Can anyone give me the right direction to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: You should try this expression: `@JMS\Exclude(if="this.getDeleted() !== null")`

Comment: nope, does not work. also if i do if="false" or if="true" the result is same. it excludes all fields, does not matter what is the condition. Also I have tried using service, but the service is not being called. but when i use service on propery, than service is called and working correctly. so generally it looks that it does not really supports @Exclude with condition on class

Comment: why not just use the softdeleteable extension? http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html

Comment: @Rufinus Thanks, i will try hopefully every part of application will work fine with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Rufinus i have used http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html  which solved my problem. Now "deleted" entities are exluded from any query so serializer returns required data only.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in symfony 4.3, but I solved it by requiring 'symfony/expression-language'

> composer require symfony/expression-language