# jms serializer @Exclude condition on class

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

My question is rather equal to [Symfony2 - JMS Serializer - Exclude entity if getDeleted() is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742033/symfony2-jms-serializer-exclude-entity-if-getdeleted-is-not-null) but the accepted answer offered a workaround and not an actual response and does not fit my requirements.

I have a class `OriginalText` and it has a `getPublic()` method that returns `true` if the entity is public. I want to exclude every entity which is not public.

```php
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Exclude;
/**
* @Exclude(if="!object.getPublic()")
*/
class OriginalText{

    public getPublic(){
    //returns true if $this->public == true
    }
}
```

However this is not working. 
As suggested, I have installed symfony/expression-language; I also tried with `!this.getPublic()`, and with `== false` insted of `!`. None of this is working.

Any idea?